# Animating between views

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

On each of my views I have this on each of my `render` methods:

```
render: function(){
    template = _.template(ViewTemplate, {foo:get});
    wrapper = this.$el;
    wrapper.is(':hidden') ? 
    wrapper.html(template).show(200) : 
    wrapper.hide(200, function(){ wrapper.html(template).show(200) });
}
```

But this is so repetitive, I was wondering how could I be implement animation between my views but not repeating the same lines of code?

Comment: What's the relation with requireJs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe just add the fade-in as a utility method to the View prototype:

```
Backbone.View.prototype.fadeIn = function(template, wrapper) {
    wrapper.is(':hidden') ? 
    wrapper.html(template).show(200) : 
    wrapper.hide(200, function(){ wrapper.html(template).show(200) });
};
```

That reduces the repetition in the `render` implementations:

```
render: function() {
    template = _.template(ViewTemplate, {foo:get});
    this.fadeIn(template, this.$el);
}
```

Comment: Or create a base view for the app that has the fade method and extend rather than modifying Backbone's view prototype.

Comment: @steveax I like that idea in theory, but isn't it easier said than done?  Would very much like to see a working example of that approach though ...